# Table isn't centering

Tags: tables

I have this code to render a table:

```
\chapter{Resultados}

\begin{table*}[h]
\centering
\caption{Resultados Para o Conjunto de 
Dados Image}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
      \hline
      Índice & Algoritmo Generativo & \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Função Consenso} \\ \hline
      - & K-Means & Agglomerative & CSPA & IVC & LWEA & LGWP \\ \hline
      ARI & \makecell{ari-km-5 \\ ari-km-10 \\ ari-km-15 \\ ari-km-20 \\ ari-km-30} & \makecell{ari-agm-km-5 \\ ari-agm-km-10 \\ ari-agm-km-15 \\ ari-agm-km-20 \\ ari-agm-km-30} & \makecell{ari-csp-km-5 \\ ari-csp-km-10 \\ ari-csp-km-15 \\ ari-csp-km-20 \\ ari-csp-km-30} & \makecell{ari-ivc-km-5 \\ ari-ivc-km-10 \\ ari-ivc-km-15 \\ ari-ivc-km-20 \\ ari-ivc-km-30} & \makecell{ ari-lwe-km-5 \\ ari-lwe-km-10 \\ ari-lwe-km-15 \\ ari-lwe-km-20 \\ ari-lwe-km-30} & \makecell{ari-lwg-km-5 \\ ari-lwg-km-10 \\ ari-lwg-km-15 \\ ari-lwg-km-20 \\ ari-lwg-km-30} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

However, the table not only isn't being centered, it is rendering too much to the right and the content is being cut off:

[image: screenprint depicting the table rendering]

How do I fix this? I'm also getting a warning `Overfull \hbox (114pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 7-13`

Comment: You can take a look at the various options presented in the answer to [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144)

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. Do you use the `geometry` package? If so, please also include the corresponding settings. Do you use a `twocolumn` documentclass and did you change the font size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not provide the key information: the length of the `\textwidth`. Not knowing it, we can only guess about it. For example, if page borders width are 25mm, than by using `\makecell` also in header of the second column then we can put your table on the page as you would like it to be:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\chapter{Resultados}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Resultados Para o Conjunto de Dados Image}
%\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|*{5}{C|}}
      \hline
Índice & \makecell{Algoritmo\\ Generativo} 
            & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Função Consenso} \\ \hline
   --  & K-Means & Agglomerative & CSPA & IVC & LWEA & LGWP \\ \hline
  ARI & \makecell{ari-km-5 \\ ari-km-10 \\ ari-km-15 \\ ari-km-20 \\ ari-km-30} 
    & \makecell{ari-agm-km-5 \\ ari-agm-km-10 \\ ari-agm-km-15 \\ ari-agm-km-20 \\ ari-agm-km-30} 
        & \makecell{ari-csp-km-5 \\ ari-csp-km-10 \\ ari-csp-km-15 \\ ari-csp-km-20 \\ ari-csp-km-30} 
            & \makecell{ari-ivc-km-5 \\ ari-ivc-km-10 \\ ari-ivc-km-15 \\ ari-ivc-km-20 \\ ari-ivc-km-30} 
                & \makecell{ ari-lwe-km-5 \\ ari-lwe-km-10 \\ ari-lwe-km-15 \\ ari-lwe-km-20 \\ ari-lwe-km-30} 
                    & \makecell{ari-lwg-km-5 \\ ari-lwg-km-10 \\ ari-lwg-km-15 \\ ari-lwg-km-20 \\ ari-lwg-km-30} \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Answer (score 0):

The problem, not too surprisingly, is that the table is too wide (which is why you got the `Overfull \hbox` warning).

The options are to find a way to make the table narrower (which it doesn't look like there's much hope for besides perhaps making the text smaller) or typeset the table vertically instead of horizontally using [sidewaystable](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/rotating.pdf)